# Using jQuery to check a box generated from php

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to 'check' the the 'AC:Front' box from a button click on the below website. I tried changing the checkbox to 'checked' and I also tried changing the encompassing  to class="checked".

The goal is to eventually collect the inputted VIN, run it through a decoder and use the data to fill the page.

Here is the [website](http://35.237.132.231/add-car/)

HTML

```
<div class="stm-single-feature">
                <div class="heading-font">Comfort</div>
                                                                                                    <div class="feature-single">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="A/C: Front" name="stm_car_features_labels[]"/>
                                <span>A/C: Front</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
```

CSS

```
div.checker span.checked {
  background-position: -16px 0; }
```

PHP

```
<?php
if ($items) {
    if (!empty($id)) {
        $features_car = get_post_meta($id, 'additional_features', true);
        $features_car = explode(',', $features_car);
    } else {
        $features_car = array();
    }

    foreach ($items as $item) { ?>
        <?php if(isset($item['tab_title_single'])): ?>
            <div class="stm-single-feature">
                <div class="heading-font"><?php echo $item['tab_title_single']; ?></div>
                <?php $features = explode(',', $item['tab_title_labels']); ?>
                <?php if (!empty($features)): ?>
                    <?php foreach ($features as $feature): ?>
                        <?php
                        $checked = '';
                        if (in_array($feature, $features_car)) {
                            $checked = 'checked';
                        };
                        ?>
                        <div class="feature-single">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo esc_attr($feature); ?>"
                                       name="stm_car_features_labels[]" <?php echo $checked; ?>/>
                                <span><?php echo esc_attr($feature); ?></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php }
}?>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(function($) {
                    $("#generateVin").on("click", function() {
                    var $checkbox = $("input[type=checkbox]").eq(1);
                    $checkbox.prop("checked", true);
                    $checkbox.parent().addClass("checked");
          });
  });


    </script>
```

Comment: So, what is your problem bro ??

Comment: What is your question? Does your code not work as expected? If so, what actually happens? Are there any errors in your browser console?

Comment: There are no errors in the console but the code does not actually check the box @kousheralampranto

Comment: Where is the `#generateVin` element? Are you clicking it? How about trying some debugging? Your browser probably has a debugger built-in. If not, try adding some `console.log()` lines

Comment: did you try it with `$( document ).ready(function() {});` ???

Comment: @Phil The #generateVin is a button in the form above. I tested the button already by printing to console, also tested to see what happens when the check box is clicked by the mouse and the only thing I found was that the encompassing <span> has a class added to it 'checked'. But after I use jQuery to add the class I still do not get a check mark

Comment: @kousheralampranto I have not, can give that a try rn

Comment: FYI `jQuery(function($) { ... })` is the same as `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Your problem is that `$("input[type=checkbox]").eq(1)` is matching your `<input type="checkbox" name="stm_remember_me">` checkbox in your login form. Use a more specific selector like `'#stm_sell_a_car_form input[type="checkbox"]'` and next time, include all the relevant information in your question